# php Ajax calls fails on one server

Tags: php, ajax

I copied a script that works on one server to another but it doesn't work on that server. To troubleshoot it I created a test file with just this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script>
    ShowThePopout();

    function ShowThePopout() { 
      
      console.log('show box');
      
      $.post( "sidebox_ajax_test.php", { show_cart: true })
      .done(function( data ) {
       
          console.log('good result');
          
      });
    } 
    </script>
```

The sidebox_ajax_test.php file just has this

```
    <?php
    echo 'done';
```

I uploaded the two files to both servers. When the test page is visited, on the first server the console shows

```
    show box
    XHRPOSThttp:.../sidebox_ajax_test.php
    good result
```

On the second server it shows

```
    show box
```

No errors are thrown, that I can see. Both accounts on the servers are using php 7.4. I saw many posts about a similar problem that said CORS needs to be enabled and it is on both servers. Any ideas on how to fix this or what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I tried using Chrome instead of FF and its console reported a problem loading jquery due to the link not being secure. Changed that and it worked.